# Sony Vegas or FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, software-recommendation

My Sony Vegas Licence will expire soon. Thanks to this site i found this free software FFmpeg. I also see that is largely used and has a lot of support here. Tbh i never heard of it. What would you recommend? Buy a new licence or use this free software? pros, cons?

Comment: Which non-perpetual license of Vegas do you have?

Comment: i have sony vegas pro 365, 3 months plan, still have 2 months left

Comment: You're comparing two different tools that have different uses: it's like asking if you should stop using a saw for a hammer. Vegas is an editor. The `ffmpeg` command-line tool is basically a versatile encoder (although it can be used as a simple editor with some caveats). So the answer is that you should use both.

Comment: What are you going to be using them for? Ffmpeg on its own, as a command-line tool, really shines as a helper tool to augment existing video editor software. You don't really want to be doing video editing 'without' a gui in many cases, in some cases a command line is all you need though. That said there are many video editors that do what vegas does that use ffmpeg....and they are all generally free. You should probably look at software that uses ffmpeg as being the thing that replaces vegas. So.... Go vegas + ffmpeg.exe; or find software that uses ffmpeg + ffmpeg.exe.